# Blank page and error with only a specific url with pyqt webview in python

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5, qtwebkit, qwebview

I have got an issue when using this following code with a specific url only:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView,QWebSettings


class Browser(QWebView):

    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        Settings = self.settings()
        Settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
        Settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavaEnabled, True)
        Settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        Settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, True)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._result_available)

    def _result_available(self, ok):
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        print unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = Browser()

    from_url=True
    url_to_view='https://www.twitch.tv/'
    if from_url==True:
        view.load(QUrl(url_to_view))

    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When running this code I get a blank page and this error:

```
QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be called once.
QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be called once.
```

It is very strange because I have got this issue only with the https://www.twitch.tv/ url. I had try to replace url with https://www.google.com or anything else and it works fine.

I was expecting that it was relative to `python2` and `PyQt4`, but I have got the same issue when running on `python3` and `PyQt5` implementation

Someone could help me to properly load the page with pyqt ?